# Maven settings for grails

Tags: java, maven, grails, intellij-idea, groovy

Where does grails (v2.3.6) look for maven settings?

I've tried to configure local maven repo, but grails ignores settings.xml from custom maven installation set in IDEA (v14) settings and default path `<user>\.m2\settings.xml`

The solution might be additional config file for project, where you can set this path to repo for your machine, and pass it to mavenLocal() in the BuildConfig. But why should I duplicate that info if it's already configured in local maven settings.

Comment: "but grails ignores settings.xml" - what exactly does that mean? Which steps do you take to make grails do things and stuff such that you notice that there is a configuration mis-match?

Comment: First of all, there is IDEA project settings where you specify maven installation. Settings.xml from maven conf directory is not used.

As grails consider local maven repo `<user>`\.m2\repository` (which is hardcoded as DEFAULT_CACHE) I can make an assumption it will look there for settings.xml. But it's not so, properties is not used if specified there.

Comment: I'm sure that all makes sense inside your head, but I'm too stupid to understand how any of that has anything to do with the question I asked. See: to me Grails only provides maven integration support, it does not "control" maven. So nothing in Grails will determine what settings.xml to use, that is still up to the Maven installation as configured on your system / in your IDE. Hence, no idea what you're talking about here.

Comment: "So nothing in Grails will determine what settings.xml to use" - that's exactly point of my initial question. As grails uses maven as dependency resolver it should consume maven properties. But I'm no idea where this configuration is.